# How to get IST and PST string from a date in Angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material, moment-timezone, angular-moment

I need to store IST and PST strings based on the current browser timezone.

I have used moment library to get that string, but it throws an error, I have tried several other ways as well but did not get the desired string

```
const timezone = moment.tz(moment.tz.guess()).format('z');
console.log(timezone); // eg: PST
```

Comment: what error you are getting, can you share a stackblitz with the issue replicated and output expected!

Comment: What's the problem? What is the desired string? The code you posted does work and prints what moment thinks is the browser's timezone acronym. On my machine it prints `EET`. `z` is the placeholder for the timezone acronym, not the offset or anything else. If you use `.format()` you'll get an ISO8601 string with the offset included

Comment: IST
core.mjs:9171 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'guess')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'guess')
    at SignalRService.addDeviceInfo (signal-r.service.ts:142:28)
    at signal-r.service.ts:52:18
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:372:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:26274:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:371:52)